# Converting Zip codes to Time zone for US

Tags: python

I have US ZIP codes, now I need to get their respective time zones.
Could you please help me with any mapping file or Python or R code for this.

Answer (score 6):

Use "Ziptz" library for this.
Usage:

```
z = Ziptz.new
z.time_zone_name('zipcode')
```

Result:

```
Pacific
```

Get all the zip codes in a time zone

```
 z.zips('American Samoa') #=> ["96799", "96941", "96942", "96943", "96944"]
```

Supported Timezone

- "Atlantic" UTC -04:00
- "Eastern" UTC -05:00
- "Central" UTC -06:00
- "Mountain" UTC -07:00
- "Pacific" UTC -08:00
- "Alaska" UTC -09:00
- "Hawaii-Aleutian Islands" UTC -10:00
- "American Samoa" UTC -11:00
- "Marshall Islands" UTC +12:00
- "Guam" UTC +10:00
- "Palau" UTC +09:00
- "Micronesia" UTC +11:00

For more: [ziptz](https://github.com/infused/ziptz)

For Python

Install

```
pip install pyzipcode
```

Usage:

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
zipcode = zcdb[54115]
```

To get City Name:

```
zipcode.city
```

Result

```
u'De Pere'
```

To Get Timezone

```
zipcode.timezone
```

Result:

```
-6
```

For more: [pyzipcode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcode)

Comment: is it Ruby language? or some other because i'm comfortable with Python/R

Comment: It's available in Python

Comment: Thanks for note , but in python also ziptz is the package i need to install to perform the tasks

Comment: To install in gem ziptz

Comment: for python what will be package ?

Comment: Does pyzipcode handle daytime saving? cant find such things in the documentation.

Comment: What is the baseline timezone? Can't find in documentation. Doesn't seem to be UTC or GMT.